# How to replace fragment within a ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days and it's driving me crazy. It seems like what I'm trying to do would be a pretty common use case but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

So, the problem: **I want to replace fragments within a ViewPager and maintain the normal operation of the backstack**.

My ViewPager contains two fragments that display ListViews. When in the first position of the ViewPager I want to be able to drill down into the ListView and be able to back out with the back button like so:

Artists -> Albums -> Songs

Artists <- Albums <- Songs

Each of these elements is implemented as a separate fragment containing it's own ListView.

When the user swipes to the right I want to display the current playlist in a separate fragment using the ViewPager.

So a typical flow could be:

Artists -> Albums -> `Swipe Right to Playlist fragment`-> Playlist -> `Swipe Left to return`-> Albums

After much experimentation I've managed come up with this solution which does replace the Artists/Albums fragments, however it's not possible to back out of the fragments using the back button:

```
   public interface ItemSelectedListener {
    void onItemSelected(Item item);
}

public class ListPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = RMPDApplication.APP_PREFIX + "ListPagerAdapter";
    SearchView searchView;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    AbstractListFragment firstFragment;
    PlaylistFragment playlistFragment;


    public ListPagerAdapter(SearchView searchView, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.searchView = searchView;
        fragmentManager = fm;
    }

    class FragmentChanger implements ItemSelectedListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(Item item) {
            AbstractListFragment newFragment;
            if (item instanceof Artist) {
                newFragment = new ArtistAlbumsListFragment(searchView, (Artist) item, new FragmentChanger());
            } else {
                newFragment = new SongListFragment(searchView, (Album) item);
            }

            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(firstFragment);
            ft.commit();
            firstFragment = newFragment;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 1) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Returning playlistFragment");
            if (playlistFragment == null) {
                playlistFragment = new PlaylistFragment(searchView);
            }
            return playlistFragment;

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Returning firstFragment");
            if(firstFragment == null) {
                firstFragment = new ArtistListFragment(new FragmentChanger(), searchView);
            }
            return firstFragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getItemPosition: " + object.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if(object instanceof PlaylistFragment) {
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        }
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

I pass the `FragmentChanger` to each of the fragments and then in `onItemClick()` I call it's only method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final Artist artist = (Artist) adapter.getItem(position);
    itemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(artist);
}
```

This almost works, clicking an item replaces the fragment with the desired one, but I have no way to return to the previous fragment. If anyone can help me figure this out I would be very grateful.

**Edit:**

Ok I've got it working with J.Romero's suggestion. In the end I implemented all the forward/back functionality in a single `BrowserFragment` and overrode `onBackPressed()` to handle the back button. I'll add the relevant code in case it helps anyone else.

Here is my ViewPager:

```
public class ListPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    SearchView searchView;
    BrowserFragment browserFragment;
    PlaylistFragment playlistFragment;

    public ListPagerAdapter(SearchView searchView, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.searchView = searchView;
    }

    public boolean browserFragmentCanGoBack() {
        return browserFragment.canGoBack();
    }

    public void browserFragmentBack() {
        browserFragment.goBack();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 1) {
            if (playlistFragment == null) {
                playlistFragment = new PlaylistFragment(searchView);
            }
            return playlistFragment;

        } else {
            if (browserFragment == null) {
                browserFragment = new BrowserFragment(searchView);
            }
            return browserFragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Then in the hosting activity I override `onBackPressed()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        if (pagerAdapter.browserFragmentCanGoBack()) {
            pagerAdapter.browserFragmentBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    } else {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}
```

And it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do you own managing of "backstack" by overriding the `onBackPressed` method in your activity and keeping track of which level the user is currently on and displaying or going back and activity as appropriate.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (mLevel > 1) {
        // in your case probably change the adapter item for the page
        mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    ...
}
```